# How is step calculated in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, gpu

The following source code is from the book [Programming in Parallel with CUDA](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/programming-in-parallel-with-cuda/C43652A69033C25AD6933368CDBE084C), Page: 25-26:

```
15.1     __global__ void gpu_sin(float *sums, int steps, int terms, float step_size)
15.2     {
15.3         int step = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
15.4         if(step<steps){
15.5            float x = step_size*step;
15.6            sums[step] = sinsum(x,terms); // store values
15.7         }
15.8     }
```

The book gives an explanation:

> Line 15.3 declares a variable step equivalent to the for loop index variable of the same name in line 24 of Example 1.1. It is set to a value defined by the built-in variables `blockDim.x`, `blockIdx.x` and `threadIdx.x`. The values of these variables depend
> on the launch parameters used in the host call to the kernel as follows:
>
> ○ `blockDim.x` will be set to threads, i.e., the thread block size used by the kernel.
> ○ `blockIdx.x` will be set to the rank of the thread block to which the current thread belongs and will be in the range `[0,blocks-1]`.
> ○ `threadIdx.x` will be set to the rank of the current thread within its thread block and will be in the range `[0,threads-1]`.
> ○ `step = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x` is in range `[0, threads × blocks - 1]`.

I haven't understood the last point.

How is this being calculated: `step = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x` ?

What is the rationale?

Comment: You have two indices `blockIdx.x` and `threadIdx.x` that you want to map into a single linear index with consecutive threads of the same block being mapped to consecitive indices for e.g. coalescing memory access. So you multiply the outer index `blockIdx.x` by the size of the range of the inner index `threadIdx.x`.The size of that range is `blockDim.x`. Maybe just try it out for a small block size on paper. It is quite straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a canonical method to calculate a 1D globally unique thread index.

CUDA is a massively multithreaded computational system.  In order to have each thread do something that is slightly different (for instance, calculate a unique output point in a vector), it is helpful/useful for each thread to be able to have a unique ordinal.

That is the purpose of that calculation, and you will find it extensively used in CUDA codes.  It serves a similar purpose as the rank identification in MPI, or the thread identification in multi-threading systems like OpenMP (`omp_get_thread_num()`), `std::thread` (`std::thread::id`), etc.

To learn more about the components of this calculation, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058001/cuda-griddim-blockdim-and-threadidx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619274/cuda-griddim-and-blockdim), also noting they both link to the CUDA programming guide.  The set of all threads associated with a kernel launch (the *grid*) is hierarchically decomposed first into blocks, each block having an index (`blockIdx.x`) and each block into a uniform number of threads, each thread having an index in the block (`threadIdx.x`).   Combined with the number of threads per block (`blockDim.x`), the globally unique index can be calculated by each thread.

You can get an orderly introduction to CUDA [here](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/cuda-training-series/). The first unit covers this calculation in some detail, and gives a rationale for it.

In the code example you have shown, the intent of that kernel is to populate a particular vector according to a particular formula or calculation.  The kernel code intends to do that "in parallel" assigning one thread to each output position (`step`).  The calculation of step ensures that each thread will be assigned to a unique position in the output vector (`sums`).

In [the multidimensional case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75837651/what-would-be-the-source-code-like-to-add-two-n-x-n-x-n-x-n-tensors), each thread instead of having a single index (`x`) has an ordered pair (`x`,`y`) or an ordered 3-tuple (`x`,`y`,`z`) that describes its unique position in the multidimensional grid.  The calculations shown in that other answer can provide a canonical set of calculations to assign each thread a unique tuple.